# Stop accepting input after 20 chars

Tags: c++, arrays, input, char, limit

I am trying to understand how to use cin.get(). I would like to only accept 20 characters of input, but any method I've tried using to detect further input stop

I am accepting input one character at a time and inputting it into an array like so:

```
void getInput(char arr[], int size) {
    char number = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        char number;
        cin.get(number);
        if ((number >= '0') && (number <= '9')) {
            arr[i] = number;
        }
        if ((number == ' ') || (number == '\n')) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried doing something like this, but you can see that my understanding is not excellent:

```
if (number == '\n') {
    done == true;
}
```

and wrapping the whole thing in a `while (!done)` for example, but that doesn't work in situations where I input 20 characters or less.

Comment: You don't really describe what your actual problem is. What do you expect this code to do? What does it do? What does it mean to "stop accepting input"? To report an error? To just ignore it?

Comment: Sorry @DavidSchwartz, i'll be more clear.

Basically i might input 12345678901234567890 (20 digits) and hit enter and it will work fine, but i want it to only input the first 20 digits of 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 (40 digits) and to ignore the rest. 

Right now if i enter more than 20 digits, the leftovers are included the next time I do a cin.

Comment: So you want to read a line? If so, why not write code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise a variable `int count= 1;`. With each iteration you can increment it with `count++;`and put the check

```
 if (count==20)
     break;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hey, thanks, but i'm not sure this helps. wouldn't that only break from the if loop?

Comment: @mc-lunar: Please try this. It will exit you from the for loop once you enter 20 characters. "If" is not a loop. It is a conditional statement.

Comment: that doesn't actually solve my problem - the issue is the remaining input.

Comment: @mc-lunar: What do you mean by remaining input?

Answer (score 0):

You could round down the passed `size` parameter to 20 if it's larger than 20. Then the for-loop will break at most after 20 iterations.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getInput(char arr[], size_t size) {

    const size_t MAX_SIZE = 20;
    if (MAX_SIZE < size) {
        // 'round down' size if it's too big
        size = MAX_SIZE;
    }

    char number = '0';
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin.get(number);
        if ((number >= '0') && (number <= '9')) {
            arr[i] = number;
        } else if ((number == ' ') || (number == '\n')) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char arr[32] = {};
    // even though arr could fit 32 chars
    // only MAX_SIZE=20 numbers at most will be accepted
    getInput(arr, 32);
    cout << arr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming `size` is the length of `arr` (can't yet comment so could not ask this), if so then watch out for doing `i < size + 1`; that let's `i` take values from 0 to `size` inclusive, and then the for-loop eventually reaches `arr[size]` which is off the end of the array. Use `i < size` instead.